# How to set svn:ignore without opening an editor?

Tags: svn

I want to use `svn:ignore` in a Jenkins job.

I've add `export EDITOR=vi` and it told me that:

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

How can I set ignore without open the editor? Thank you.

My usage is: `svn propedit svn:ignore ./some_folder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `propedit`, use [`propset`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.manip). Note that the `svn:ignore` value usually contains multiple lines. In shell syntax:

```
svn propset svn:ignore '*.o
*.class' ./some_folder
```

If you have the ignore list in a file:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "$(cat svn-ignore-list)" ./some_folder
```

If you want to perform some automated transformation of the current ignore list, you can use a non-interactive program as the editor. Be careful about quoting — if you're finding this hard to read, put the transformation into a script file.

```
SVN_EDITOR='sed '\''/^\*\.txt$/d'\' svn propedit svn:ignore ./some_folder
```